# How can I export file with variable?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to export my file in xlsx format. I am able to do this using 'ExportWithFormatting' (see here).

However, I would like to name my file by "File-XXXX" with XXXX a value retrieved from my form.

I tried several things which failed like:
[image]

Comment: what format is the date stored?
if it is in dd/mm/yyyy it will not go out properly as filenames cannot have / in their names.
before exporting change date format to dd.mm.yyyy or use other allowed symbols

Comment: Convert the macro to vba and provide the value in code.

Comment: In dd/mm/yyyy, I can change to dd.mm.yyyy.

How to convert the macro to vba easly ? I don't master vba :(

Comment: There's an option in the macro designer in access to convert it to VBA. Access will do it for you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hy, it would be best if you program it in VBA.
Here is an example how to do it :

```
Public Function ExportExcelFile(ByVal strFilePath, strFileName As String) As Boolean

    'Example : ? ExportExcelFile("C\MyDocuments\","TestFileName.xlsx")
    
    Dim strQueryName As String
    Dim strFilePathFull As String
    
    Call DoCmd.Hourglass(True)
    
    strFilePathFull = strFilePath & strFileName
    
    strQueryName = "qselPriceListExport"
    
    Call DoCmd.OutputTo(acOutputQuery, strQueryName, acFormatXLSX, strFilePathFull, Autostart:=False)
    
    ExportExcelFile = True
    
    Call DoCmd.Hourglass(False)
    
End Function
```

To implement this, for example on a form you can go to lets say the button, go to events and select On Click then select the bottom most option, afterwards VBA IDE will open.
Here you can paste the code bellow :

```
Private Sub btnYourButtonNameHere_Click()

     call ExportExcelFile("C\MyDocuments\","TestFileName.xlsx")

End Sub
```

Comment: hello, I have error like `The Microsoft access database engine could not find the TestFileName object. Check that it exists and that you have correctly entered a name and its path` . However I correctly changed the variables with good values... Any idea? thank you very much